# How to get the mouse coordinate inside an OpenTK.GLControl?

Tags: c#, opentk

I have a program that uses OpenTk.GLControl.  Now on my listener, every time the mouse hovers to the said control, say "glControl1", I want to get the mouse coordinates.

Is that possible?  sample code below.

```
private void glControl1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get the current mouse coordinates       
    // .........
}
```

Answer (score 2):

OpenTK.GLControl inherits from [System.Windows.Forms.Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx). You can use the following code snippet to get the mouse position:

```
private void glControl1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control control = sender as Control;
    Point pt = control.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
}
```

Please refer to the MSDN WinForms documentation for more information.

Comment: Use the MouseMove event instead. This gives you the local coordinate of the mouse pointer in the e parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using the wrong event. Many UI actions in WinForms trigger multiple events per action; Hover is used for things like popping up tooltips. You don't get a coordinate in Hover because it's unnecessary.

What you want is the MouseMove event. This is used to track the mouse position:

```
    private void glControl1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        foo = e.X;
        bar = e.Y;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know, what is OpenTk.GLControl, but:

I was handling swipe events on Windows Phone and did this:

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //string to save coordinates of tap
        TapCoordinatesXBegin = e.GetPosition(LayoutRoot).X.ToString();
        TapCoordinatesYBegin = e.GetPosition(LayoutRoot).Y.ToString();
    }
```

And i dont remember such event MouseHover - maybe MouseEnter?